# Failed UPDATE with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query which will update `reorder_level` based on how much of an item was sold within a particular time period.

```
with a as (select invoice_itemized.itemnum, inventory.itemname, 
sum(invoice_itemized.quantity) as sold 

from invoice_itemized 

join inventory on invoice_itemized.itemnum=inventory.itemnum and 
inventory.vendor_number='COR' and inventory.dept_id='cigs' 

join invoice_totals on 
invoice_itemized.invoice_number=invoice_totals.invoice_number and 
invoice_totals.datetime>=dateadd(month,-1,getdate())

group by invoice_itemized.itemnum, inventory.itemname)

update inventory 

set reorder_level = case when a.sold/numpervencase>=5 then 30
                         when a.sold/numpervencase>=2 then 20
                         when a.sold/numpervencase>=1 then 5
                         else 1 end, 
reorder_quantity = 1

from a 

join inventory_vendors on a.itemnum=inventory_vendors.itemnum
```

Replacing the `update` with a `select` performs entirely as expected, returning proper results from the `case` and selecting 94 rows.

with the `update` in place, all of the areas affected by the update (6758) got set to 1.

Comment: What is the data type of `quantity` and `numpervencase`?  Sounds like you might have an integer division problem.

Comment: Also, if you comment out `update inventory` and everything after it, and insert `select * from a`, do you get expected results?  i.e. is your sum with those specific vendor conditions working as expected?

Comment: You don’t need the CTE. Just an update with a join

Comment: Can't advice you what is wrong as you does not provide sufficient information at all. To verify your query, first change the `UPDATE` to a `SELECT` query and check that the rows return is the required. Once you got the `SELECT` query correct, just change it to a `UPDATE` query

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: The possible issue of having more rows updated than expected: is itemnum a primary key in inventory_vendors? If not, you might need to put more lookup fields to your last join. That might also explain why you don't get the correct updated values - you might face a nondeterministic update (lookup condition returns more than one row and the updated field gets a value from 1 "random" row).

Comment: I believe so @DávidLaczkó, There aren't any rows with `NULL` in that column at any rate. All of the rest of the data in that table also is specific to one `itemnum`

Comment: @squirrel the `select` shown in the answer below returns the proper results, no problems with integer division (that's what i though at first too, but `cast` didn't solve the problem) but the `update` does not. I can't seem to figure why.

Answer (score 1):

Run this, and eyeball the results:

```
with a as (select invoice_itemized.itemnum, inventory.itemname, 
sum(invoice_itemized.quantity) as sold 

from invoice_itemized 

join inventory on invoice_itemized.itemnum=inventory.itemnum and 
inventory.vendor_number='COR' and inventory.dept_id='cigs' 

join invoice_totals on 
invoice_itemized.invoice_number=invoice_totals.invoice_number and 
invoice_totals.datetime>=dateadd(month,-1,getdate())

group by invoice_itemized.itemnum, inventory.itemname)

select a.sold, numpervencase, a.sold/numpervencase, 
case 
  when a.sold/numpervencase>=5 then 30
  when a.sold/numpervencase>=2 then 20
  when a.sold/numpervencase>=1 then 5
  else 1 
end, 
*

from a 

join inventory_vendors on a.itemnum=inventory_vendors.itemnum
```

Always a good idea to select before update to check that data ends up as you expect

> all of the areas affected by the update got set to 1

I put the raw ingredients into the query above; see if the sums worked out as expected. You might need to cast one of the operands to something with decimal places:

```
1/2 = 0
1.0/2 = 0.5
```

> And it updated far more rows than i was expecting

Every row that comes out of that select will be updated. Identify the rows you don't want to update and put a where clause in to remove them

> Am i overthinking this?

Undertesting, probably

> Do I even need the cte?

Makes it easier to represent, but no- you could get the same result by pasting the contents of the cte in as a subquery.. it's what the db does (effectively) anyway

> Do i have my from statement in the wrong place?

We don't know what result you're after so that one is impossible to answe beyond "doing so would probably generate a syntax error, so.. no"

The actual problem seems to be

- your case when is always going to ELSE, find out why
- your cte selects too many rows (I couldn't tell if the number you posted was the number you got or the number you were expecting but it's pretty moot without example data), find out why

Comment: So this select has returned only 94 rows, which is about what i was expecting. It also returns the proper values for `a.sold/numpervencase` and displays decimals correctly. The case statement is also working properly and returning the values that I want. What then could be the difference causing the `UPDATE` Version to perform incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. When I added another `join` to the `update` it worked correctly. i had to add `join inventory on inventory_vendors.itemnum=inventory.itemnum`